# Geometry messed up after applying boolean modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I don't really know how to ask this question, so I'll illustrate with pics.  I'm trying to model a sphere with two legs, using as less polygons as possible since will need to make a massive array later.  It looks like the easiest way is to model three cubes, add booleans and a subsurf modifier to make it smooth.

[image]

These are the cubes with the subsurf before applying boolean.  I intend to merge all of the meshes in only one but without losing the sharp corners between the legs and the top sphere.  If I apply the boolean, I'm getting something like this

[image]

The reason why I'm joining the geometries is because I need to apply an array later and modifiy each molecule independently.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Boolean Union should be fine for that. Note that geometry might change if Boolean wasn't the first modifier in stack when you applied it.

Comment: Easiest way would be to separate the objects (sphere and legs) into two objects with separate modifiers Then merge them later. You keep your geometry, and should still work as you want it to later